# Why can't I reproject from HARN State Plane Ft Intl to State Plane Ft?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I'm attempting to reproject a feature class that is:

```
NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601_Feet_Intl
```

to our standard, which is:

```
NAD_1983_StatePlane_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601_Feet
```

When I use the Project tool it automatically selects this transformation:

```
NAD_1983_To_HARN_WA_OR
```

But when it finishes, the two feature classes are not aligned propery.

[image: Misalignment]

Now there are a gob of other transformations, but how do I really know which one to choose? I've always been a little confused by this.

[image: Transformations]

Is the 3 ft misalignment to be expected?

Thanks for any guidance.

---

EDIT

I tried this transformation:

```
NAD_1983_HARN_To_WGS_1984_2 + WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983
```

And now the misalignment is well under a foot. But is this acceptable? To just choose a transformation that works best? And is it a true statement that after the reprojection there may be no transformation that aligns the reprojected data perfectly?

[image: Closer]

Comment: If you're comparing the original and reprojected datasets in ArcMap, did you set the transformation there too? Use the same transformation that you used in the tool. If you're comparing the reprojected data against other/reference data, check the original against it. Maybe the reference data is already using "HARN" and its metadata is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Okay, if I add the reprojected dataset first and the original dataset second - then the dataframe is in NAD_1983_StatePlane_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601_Feet. If I then set the dataframe transformation the same as for the tool, they do line up perfectly. But to me this doesn't necessarily mean the transformation was correct does it? Essentially, couldn't I use any of those transformations and if I used the same one in the tool as in the dataframe, they will line up? Right? But, how do I know which transformation is the correct one to use?

Comment: Checking tfm results means comparing against some other corresponding known to be in the output coordinate system or by knows what the offsets/target values should be. Check the geographic_transformations.pdf file in ArcGIS home, Documentation folder and go by area of use and accuracy.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at it. I was actually hoping that you would respond. I know your name from the ESRI forums. What section of the new forums do I ask projection related questions? And lastly, can you recommend a good resource/book for understanding coordinate systems/datums/transformations for someone who doesn't have an advanced math degree?

Comment: I created a map projections 'group' - but just tag any content with "map projections" or "projections" and I'll see it. Check presentations from early Dev Summits. I think the UC ones aren't available, but you can try those too.